# JS Function Not working from KeyCode / How can i call this JS function with keyboard key

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a simple script function `getSelectedText()` that is working on `button` click. It means that when we select any text and click on the button, the function is creating a new `NEWCLASS` div successfully. But now I want to use a shortcut key, like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to get selected text in the `NEWCLASS` div.

I tried this code but it doesn't work. Please, check it and let me know what mistake I am making here.

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```

**My code:**

```js
// Function to get the Selected Text  
function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = '';
  // #### create a new element with variable (nw) #### //
  var nw = document.createElement("div"); // Element's tag
  nw.className = "NEWCLASS"; // Element's class name
  // some applied style

  // window.getSelection 
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
  }
  // document.getSelection 
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
  }
  // document.selection 
  else if (document.selection) {
    selectedText =
      document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  // #### get the Selected text appended to body #### //
  nw.innerHTML = selectedText;
  document.getElementsByClassName('maintitle')[0].prepend(nw); // Append element to body
}
```

```html
<button id="mybtn" onclick="getSelectedText()">Button</button>

<p>Select any part of this sentence and press the button. Select any part of this sentence and press the button. Select any part of this sentence and press the button</p>

<div class="maintitle"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ctrl key with w will close the chrome browser so I used "Z" key for that you can replace the key code with whatever you want.

[Find the keycodes here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)

```js
const keySelected = new Set();

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    keySelected.add(e.which);
    if(keySelected.has(17) && keySelected.has(90)){
        getSelectedText();
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
     keySelected.delete(e.which);
});


/*
//jquery code if anyone want 
$(document).ready(function(){

  const keySelected = new Set();

  $(document).keydown(function (e) {
       keySelected.add(e.which);
       if(keySelected.has(17) && keySelected.has(90)){
           getSelectedText()
       }
  });
  
  $(document).keyup(function (e) {
     keySelected.delete(e.which);
  });

});

*/



// Function to get the Selected Text  
function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = '';
  // #### create a new element with variable (nw) #### //
  var nw = document.createElement("div"); // Element's tag
  nw.className = "NEWCLASS"; // Element's class name
   // some applied style

  // window.getSelection 
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
  }
  // document.getSelection 
  else if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
  }
  // document.selection 
  else if (document.selection) {
    selectedText =
      document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  // #### get the Selected text appended to body #### //
  nw.innerHTML = selectedText;
  document.getElementsByClassName('maintitle')[0].prepend(nw); // Append element to body
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybtn" onclick="getSelectedText()">Button</button>

  <p>
          Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button. Select any part of this sentence 
          and press the button
   </p> 
          
  <div class="maintitle"> </div>
```

Comment: LOL ... i fall for it. accidently closed the window.! :D

Comment: Yes most of the browsers do

Comment: `which` is deprecated. You should not use it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to recall the event on the button, you should be capable of detect the press of the key you want and call the function, like:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.code === 'keyW')    {
        getSelectedText();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> is not such a good choice, as on Windows it is a common shortcut key for closing the current Window or document, so your script will not even get the key event.

But I'll pick <kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd> instead.

You should not use the deprecated [`keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) property -- nor the [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) property which another answer suggests -- notice the red notice in the MDN documentation.

It is even easier with the [`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) property. And you can use the [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) property to know whether the control key is down.

I would use the keydown instead of the keyup event, as you can then cancel any default effect of the key, with a call to [`cancelDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key == "y") {
        event.preventDefault();
        getSelectedText();
    }
});

// Your original code:
function getSelectedText() {
  var selectedText = '';
  var nw = document.createElement("div"); // Element's tag
  nw.className = "NEWCLASS"; // Element's class name
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection();
  } else if (document.getSelection) {
    selectedText = document.getSelection();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
  } else return;
  nw.innerHTML = selectedText;
  document.getElementsByClassName('maintitle')[0].prepend(nw);
}
```

```html
<button id="mybtn" onclick="getSelectedText()">Button</button>
<p>Select any part of this sentence and press the button or enter Ctrl+Y.
   Select any part of this sentence and press the button or enter Ctrl+Y.
   Select any part of this sentence and press the button or enter Ctrl+Y.
</p> 
<div class="maintitle"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
input.keypress("w", function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("myBtn").click();
  }
});
```